# Return to first Loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

```
for(Integer i : list1)
    for(Integer x : list2)
        if(i.equals(x))
             continue;
```

all i want to do, is when i.equals(x), cancel second loop(for(Integer x : list2)) and continue with next element of list1.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Then you should use `break` instead of `continue`. `break` ends the execution of the innermost enclosing loop, exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Putting a 'break' solves your problem. If you want to use 'continue' you can do that by labeling the first for loop

```
MAIN: for(Integer i : list1)
        for(Integer x : list2)
           if(i.equals(x))
               continue MAIN;
```

Check this link for more info
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html